# How do I check if a string contains ANY element in an array

Tags: python, arrays, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to detect if a string contains any element in an array. I want to know if the string(msg) has any element from the array(prefixes) in it.

I want this because I want to make a discord bot with multiple prefixes, heres my garbage if statement.

```
if msg.startswith(prefixes[any]):
```

Comment: You'll have to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Can you show some sample code, input and output.

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to check if ``any`` ``element`` is ``in`` the ``string`` ``for`` each ``element`` ``in`` the ``array``?

Comment: Are you trying to search for any substring (as you say), or any _prefix_ (as your code implies)? Do you have any performance requirements? How many prefixes do you need to handle (like, order of magnitude, <10, <100, etc.) ?

Comment: Your title says check if the "string contains" an element, but your code shows a check if the "string starts with" an element. Which do you need?

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers show two ways of doing a linear search, and this is probably your best choice.

If you need something more scalable (ie, you have a *lot* of potential prefixes, they're very long, and/or you need to scan very frequently) then you could write a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). That's the canonical search structure for this problem, but it's obviously a *lot* more work and you still need to profile to see if it's really worthwhile for your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
prefixes = ('a','b','i')

if msg.startswith(prefixes):
```

The `prefixes` must be tuple because startswith function does not supports lists as a parameter.

Comment: I dont exactly know how to put that in my code, I updated the post to include a bit more. Sorry I didnt do it from the beginning, I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: @Tal okay, no problem. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are algorithms for such a search, however, a functional implementation in Python may look like this:

```py
prefixes = ['foo', 'bar']
string = 'foobar'
result = any(map(lambda x: string.startswith(x), prefixes))
```

If you search for `x` at any position in `string`, then change `string.startswith(x)` to `x in string`.

**UPDATE**
According to [@MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) in comments, the following is a more readable (possibly more efficient) statement:

```py
result = any(string.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes)
```

Comment: FWIW, ``any(string.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes))`` is likely better to understand instead of the ``map`` + ``lambda`` combination.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Exactly. I guess it is more efficient as well.